# Cannot print to console using yield return

Tags: c#, .net, yield-return

In the tests below, I cannot get Console.WriteLine to really print when using yield return.
I'm experimenting with yield return and I understand I have something missing in my understanding of it, but cannot find out what it is. Why aren't the strings printed inside `PrintAllYield`?

Code:

```
class Misc1 {
    public IEnumerable<string> PrintAllYield(IEnumerable<string> list) {
        foreach(string s in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(s); // doesn't print 
            yield return s;
        }
    }
    public void PrintAll(IEnumerable<string> list) {
        foreach(string s in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(s); // surely prints OK
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestFixture]
class MiscTests {
    [Test]
    public void YieldTest() {
        string[] list = new[] { "foo", "bar" };
        Misc1 test = new Misc1();

        Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAllYield");
        test.PrintAllYield(list);
        Console.WriteLine("End PrintAllYield");

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAll");
        test.PrintAll(list);
        Console.WriteLine("End PrintAll");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start PrintAllYield
End PrintAllYield

Start PrintAll
foo
bar
End PrintAll

1 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, took 0,39 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to actually enumerate the returned `IEnumerable` to see the output:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Start PrintAllYield");
    foreach (var blah in test.PrintAllYield(list))
        ; // Do nothing
    Console.WriteLine("End PrintAllYield");
```

When you use the `yield return` keyword, the compiler will construct a state machine for you. Its code will only be run when you actually use it to iterate the returned enumerable.

Is there a particular reason you're trying to use `yield return` to print out a sequence of `string`s? That's not really the purpose of the feature, which is to simplify the creation of sequence generators, rather than the enumeration of an already generated sequence. `foreach` is the preferred method for the latter.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. So the call PrintAllYield only constructs the state machine but the body is executed when the returned enumerable is iterated.

Comment: @henginy Exactly. Every time you call `MoveNext()` on the returned object it will run until it hits a `yield return` (or `yield break`).

Comment: Thanks. By the way, my actual purpose is not printing strings, it was there only for debugging purposes. The actual code scans directories and processes the files in them. I used yield return to establish a pipe for streaming execution.